# asyncio.CancelledError not caught

Tags: python, python-asyncio

Why is the `CancelledError` not caught in this example?

```
import asyncio

q = asyncio.Queue()

async def getter():
    try:
        v = await q.get()
        print(f"getter got {v}")
    except asyncio.CancelledError:
        print("getter cancelled")

async def test():
    task = asyncio.ensure_future(getter())
    task.cancel()
    await task

def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(test())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I excpected to get the "getter cancelled" message, but received a stack trace instead:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ce.py", line 22, in 
    main()
  File "ce.py", line 19, in main
    loop.run_until_complete(test())
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 468, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
concurrent.futures._base.CancelledError
```

[Task.cancel](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.Task.cancel) states:

> This arranges for a CancelledError to be thrown into the wrapped
>   coroutine on the next cycle through the event loop. The coroutine then
>   has a chance to clean up or even deny the request using
>   try/except/finally.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is that `getter` didn't even *start* executing, which you can confirm by adding a print at its beginning. Since the `try` block was never entered, the `except` didn't run either.

This happens because, in contrast to `await`, `ensure_future` doesn't start executing the coroutine right away, it just schedules it to run at the next event loop iteration, like `call_soon` does for ordinary functions. Since you cancel the task immediately, it gets removed from the runnable set and its coroutine gets closed without ever having started.

Add an `await asyncio.sleep(0)` before `task.cancel()` and you should observe the behavior you expect. I suspect you don't need to make such change in your actual code - in the unlikely case that the task gets cancelled before it ran, as in the example, it won't get a chance to acquire the resources that try/except cleans up in the first place.

Two tangential remarks:

- You probably want to re-raise `asyncio.CancelledError` after handling it, otherwise it will be suppressed. That's not a problem in `getter` as shown in the question, but it could be an issue if the code were buried in a function call. Even better, consider using `finally` or `with`, which propagate the exception and ensure that the resources are released regardless of exception type.
- When you need to create a task and run a coroutine, `loop.create_task` is [preferred](https://github.com/python/asyncio/issues/477#issuecomment-268709555) to `asyncio.ensure_future`. In short, although both do the same thing for coroutines, `create_task` makes the intention clearer; `ensure_future` is designed to accept a wider range of objects and procure a future of an unspecified type.

Comment: Yes, `create_task` is at least a much better name, but it was added only recently and is not available in 3.6.

Comment: @VPfB That is true for `asyncio.create_task`, a shorthand for `get_event_loop().create_task(...)`. However, the `create_task` [method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.AbstractEventLoop.create_task) on the event loop has been there since the beginning.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question and adding precise information about `create_task`